# ngx-cookiesconsent throwing error Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)

Tags: cookies, angular10

I'm using Angular 10 and trying to use the package ngx-cookiesconsent. I am getting an error from ngx-cookieconsent saying:

```
ERROR in node_modules/ngx-cookieconsent/cookieconsent.module.d.ts:7:53 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
    
 static forRoot(config: NgcCookieConsentConfig): ModuleWithProviders;
```

I believe that I have it wired up correctly in my app.module.ts file as such:

```
imports: [
    NgcCookieConsentModule.forRoot(cookieConfig),
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MaterialModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AccountModule
  ],
```

ngx-cookieconsent does have that method properly declared (in version 2.2.3) as seen https://github.com/tinesoft/ngx-cookieconsent/blob/master/src/cookieconsent.module.ts.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I didn't have the paths right in my angular.json file.